# Destination Host Unreachable when pinging but the laptop is connected to internet and its visible to the ISP modem

Tags: networking, 18.04, router

I have a PC and a laptop connected to the local network. Both have Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop, and both are visible to the modem:

[image]

But when I try to ping the laptop from the pc it says: `Destination Host Unreachable` :

```
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo ping 192.168.1.9
PING 192.168.1.9 (192.168.1.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

On the laptop there is no active firewall:

```
(base) marco@marco-U365G:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

This is /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml of the laptop:

```
network
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  # renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.9/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

I tried to use nmap from both pc and laptop:

```
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-05-06 18:28 CEST
Nmap scan report for www.adsl.vf (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.00045s latency).
MAC Address: 74:36:6D:9A:5A:63 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for pc (192.168.1.7)
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.77 seconds
```

And from the laptop:

```
(base) marco@marco-U365G:~$ nmap -sn 192.168.1.9/24

Starting Nmap 7.60 (https://nmap.org ) at 2021-05-06 18:29 CEST
Nmap scan report for_gateway (192.168.1.1)
Host is uo (0.00075s latency)
Nmap scan report for marco-U365C (192.168.1.9)
Host is uo (0.000054s latency)
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 3.21 seconds
```

In the laptop I also pinged to localhost, to check if the network interface is up:

```
(base) marco@marco-U354G:~$ oung 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
```

Actually I realized that pinging to other devices doesn't work either:

[image]

(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo ping 192.168.1.3
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

I realized that this is happening, may be, since the router change by he Internet Service Provider.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you able to ping anything else on the local network? A printer or something similar? Some ISP-provided devices will drop certain types of network traffic …

Comment: @matigo Thanks to your suggestion, I realized that pinging to other devices doesn't work either. I tried to ping a smartphone connected to the local network, and it doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to ping the gateway itself?  192.168.1.1

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes. from both PC and laptop pinging the gateway itself with `ping 192.168.1.` does't loose any packet

Comment: @Raphael10 do the other devices on your network have firewalls enabled on them which may be blocking pings?

Comment: @ThomasWard the laptop has no firewall set: `Status: inactive` while the other devices are smartphones, which have no firewalls at all

Comment: Is your connection wired or wireless? Some routers turn on by default so called "guest mode" in wireless networks, which disables communications between different devices in the local network. They can only communicate with the router itself and with Internet via the router. Check if there is a possibility to turn this off in your router.

Comment: @raj The connection is wired: both PC and laptop are connected with cables to the ISP's router. While the smartphones were connected via wireless

Comment: That seems really strange, as for wired connection such routers usually have just a simple switch built in, that doesn't restrict traffic in any way.